# Tkinter Image Croping Tool: Using multiple rectangles to crop image, adding scroll bar makes position error in rectagle

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just a beginner in Python & Tkinter,  I'm trying to write an application to crop multiple areas in an image and save them as separate images, I can crop the images by drawing the multiple rectangles, but after adding a scrollbar the mouse positions goes wrong while drawing the rectangle using the mouse pointer it is placed little away due to the scrolling effect.

I'm also trying to add zoom in and zoom out could you please suggest me how to achieve this.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1200, 800
topx, topy, botx, boty = 0, 0, 0, 0
rect_id = None
path = "test.jpg"
rect_list = list()
rect_main_data = list()
ImageFilePath = ""
ImgOpen = None
prodDir = ""
ImageFound = False

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Image Croping Tool")
window.geometry('%sx%s' % (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
window.configure(background='grey')

ImageFrame = tk.Frame(window, width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT - 70, borderwidth=1)
ImageFrame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
ImageFrame.place(x=0,y=71)

rawImage = Image.open("test.jpg")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rawImage)

canvasWidth, canvasHeight = rawImage.size
canvas = tk.Canvas(ImageFrame, width=canvasWidth, height=canvasHeight - 70, borderwidth=2, highlightthickness=2,scrollregion=(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight))

def get_mouse_posn(event):
    global topy, topx
    topx, topy = event.x, event.y

def update_sel_rect(event):
    global rect_id
    global topy, topx, botx, boty
    botx, boty = event.x, event.y
    canvas.coords(rect_id, topx, topy, botx, boty)  # Update selection rect.

def draw_rect(self):
    draw_data = canvas.create_rectangle(topx,topy,botx,boty,outline="green", fill="")
    rect_list.append((topx,topy,botx,boty))
    rect_main_data.append(draw_data)
    
def GetImageFilePath():
    global ImageFilePath
    global ImageFound
    global img
    global canvas
    global ImageFrame
    test = False
    if (ImageFound):
        canvas.destroy()
        canvas = tk.Canvas(ImageFrame, width=canvasWidth, height=canvasHeight - 70, borderwidth=2, highlightthickness=2,scrollregion=(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight))
        
    ImageFilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    
    ImgOpen = Image.open(ImageFilePath)

    if len(ImageFilePath) > 0:  
        test = True                          
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(ImageFilePath))        
        ImageFound = True        

        
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=tk.NW)
        
        
        canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT,expand=False,fill=tk.BOTH)
        rect_id = canvas.create_rectangle(topx, topy, topx, topy, dash=(2,2), fill='', outline='red')
        canvas.bind('<Button-1>', get_mouse_posn)
        canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', update_sel_rect)
        canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',draw_rect)   
        canvas.update()
             
    if (test):
        window.mainloop() 
def testPrint():
    print("Hello")


def cropImages():
    im = Image.open(ImageFilePath)    
    mainDir = os.path.dirname(ImageFilePath)
    global prodDir
    prodDir = os.path.splitext(ImageFilePath)[0]
    if not os.path.exists(prodDir):
        os.makedirs(prodDir)
    i=0
    for po in rect_list:
        i= i +1
        img1 = im.crop((po[0], po[1], po[2], po[3]))
        print(os.path.join(prodDir,"img" + str(i) + ".jpg"))
        img1.save(os.path.join(prodDir,"img" + str(i) + ".jpg"))
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Completed ", "Croped all the images") 

def clearRectangles():
    global rect_main_data
    global rect_list
        
    if (len(rect_main_data) > 0):
        for rect in rect_main_data:
            canvas.delete(rect)    
    rect_main_data.clear()
    rect_list.clear()
    
    canvas.pack()
    window.mainloop()

TitleBar = tk.LabelFrame(window,width=2000,height=70, borderwidth=1)
TitleBar.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')
TitleBar.place(x=0,y=0)

tiletest = tk.Label(window,text="Image Cropping Tool", anchor=tk.NE)
tiletest.pack()

openFile = tk.Button(TitleBar,text = "Open Image",command = GetImageFilePath,width=10, height=2)
openFile.place(x=10,y=10)
cropImages = tk.Button(TitleBar,text = "Crop Images",command = cropImages,width=10, height=2)
cropImages.place(x=140,y=10)
clearImages = tk.Button(TitleBar,text = "Clear",command = clearRectangles,width=10, height=2)
clearImages.place(x=270,y=10)

if (ImageFound):
    canvas.delete(img)
    canvas.update()
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=tk.NW)
rect_id = canvas.create_rectangle(topx, topy, topx, topy, dash=(2,2), fill='', outline='red')
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', get_mouse_posn)
canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', update_sel_rect)
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',draw_rect) 

hbar=tk.Scrollbar(ImageFrame,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.X)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
vbar=tk.Scrollbar(ImageFrame,orient=tk.VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT,expand=False,fill=tk.BOTH)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `event.x` and `event.y` are always relative to the upper-left corner of canvas.  If the canvas is not scrolled, they match with the *real* coordinates.  But not when the canvas is scrolled.

However you can use `canvas.canvasx()` and `canvas.canvasy()` functions to convert the mouse position to the *real* coordinates in the canvas:

```
def get_mouse_posn(event):
    global topy, topx
    topx, topy = canvas.canvasx(event.x), canvas.canvasy(event.y) # convert to real canvas coordinates

def update_sel_rect(event):
    global botx, boty
    botx, boty = canvas.canvasx(event.x), canvas.canvasy(event.y) # convert to real canvas coordinates
    canvas.coords(rect_id, topx, topy, botx, boty)  # Update selection rect.
```

Comment: This helps a lot, I have an issue in a rectangle creation when new images are loaded the red rectangle does not show up.
rect_id = canvas.create_rectangle(topx, topy, topx, topy, dash=(2,2), fill='', outline='red')

Comment: First you need to declare `rect_id` as global inside `GetImageFilePath()` function.  Second you need to put the new image loaded at the lowest z-order using `canvas.lower()`.